# Как на Android узнать реальное разрешение экрана/окна браузера из JS? Как на Android задать элементу размер в реальных пикселях?

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, mobile-web

Товарищ делает некое внутреннее корпоративное web-приложение под заранее известные модели смартфонов с заранее известными разрешениями экранов. По ходу выполнения работ заметили, что браузерное разрешение не совпадает с реальным разрешением экрана.

Была сделана тестовая web-страничка со следующим кодом:

```js
const dataEl = document.querySelector('.data');
const data = {};

update();

window.addEventListener('resize', update);
document.documentElement.addEventListener('resize', update);
document.body.addEventListener('resize', update);

function update() {
  Object.assign(data, {
    htmlClientWidth: document.documentElement.clientWidth,
    htmlClientHeight: document.documentElement.clientHeight,
    bodyClientWidth: document.body.clientWidth,
    bodyClientHeight: document.body.clientHeight,
    bodyPageWidth: document.body.pageWidth,
    bodyPageHeight: document.body.pageHeight,
    screenWidth: screen.width,
    screenHeight: screen.height,
    screenAvailWidth: screen.availWidth,
    screenAvailHeight: screen.availHeight,
    windowInnerWidth: window.innerWidth,
    windowInnerHeight: window.innerHeight,
    windowOuterWidth: window.outerWidth,
    windowOuterHeight: window.outerHeight,
    windowDevicePixelRatio: window.devicePixelRatio
  });
  dataEl.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);
}
```

```css
html,
body,
.data {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.box {
  position: fixed;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />
</head>

<body>
  <pre class="data">
      
    </pre>
  <div class='box'></div>
</body>

</html>
```

А отображается она примерно так:

[image: Разрешение экрана]

По файлу скриншота должно быть видно *(если хостинг не сожмёт картинку)*, что разрешение экрана 1080х2160.

Значения параметров также видны на скриншоте. Блок, которому заданы широта и высота по `500px`, на скриншоте имеет размер в 960 пикселей.

Собственно, вопрос, что это за браузерная самодеятельность? Существуют ли нормальные браузеры и эмуляторы web-view, которые отображают всякие векторные изображения, которые делались специально для отображения разной мелко-пиксельной информации без всякого попадания ровных горизонтальных и вертикальных линий в между-пиксельные пространства?

Comment: Всё нормально, просто учитывайте devicePixelRatio при интерпретации размеров (960 поделить на 1.925 получится как раз примерно 500). CSS-пиксели не всегда совпадают с реальными пикселями

Comment: Зато меня волнует другой вопрос: значение devicePixelRatio какое-то у вас странное, хотя обычно оно довольно «круглое» без этой странной мешанины в дробной части (1.5 или 2 или 3 в зависимости от устройства)

Comment: @andreymal да аппарат большой 7". Может из-за этого. 1.925 ну хоть так. Вроде уже почти круглое число. Придется генерить svg для отображения на лету, читая этот `devicePixelRatio`. Что поделать. Кстати, а в css его никак не получить? чтобы сам `calc()` решал, какой размер генерировать.